# Batch script to get matching expression file name in a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Using batch script, I go inside folder and in that folder, I've different files like -

```
ABc.txt
Pqr.png
.
.
Test-1.2.0.zip
```

Out of these file, I want to get name of a file which starts with `Test` and has extension `.zip`. In this case, `Test-1.2.0.zip`. As its version could be dynamic.

Could you please help me with the batch script to find `Test-1.2.0.zip` and return is as output?

The code I tried was

```
for /f %%i in (^Test*.zip$) do echo "%%~i"
```

but it results into an error - %%i was unexpected at this time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try `Test*.zip`?

Comment: I tried `for /f %%i in (^Test*.zip$) do echo "%%~i"` but it results into an error  -  `%%i was unexpected at this time`

Comment: as far as I know you cannot use regex in cmd this way. You may switch to Powershell or simply use `dir /B Test*.zip`  ... and btw: You should add this to your question ... not as comment!

Comment: The error message you are getting is unrelated to your parenthesized string, it is because you appear to be using batch-file syntax directly in cmd.exe. to do it in a batch file you'd use `%%i`, and in cmd, you'd use just `%i`. Regardless of that, the file glob you are using appears to be a regular expression type of glob, as used by `findstr.exe` and not directly by the cmd.exe parser.

Comment: Additionally the answer you have accepted, does not identify only files which meet the intent of your glob. Due to 8.3 file naming, which is enabled by default in Windows, it locates files which begin with the case insensitive string `test` and have an extension which begins with `.zip`, it does not select only files which have an extension `.zip`. It would for instance identify `testingData.zipx`, which does not meet the criteria of your specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %i in (Test*.zip) do echo "%~i"
```

should work for you from the prompt.

```
for %%i in (Test*.zip) do echo "%%~i"
```

should work within a batch file.

You could replace the `echo "%%~i"` with `set "filename=%%~i"` and then the name found, if  any would be stored in the environment variable `filename`.